# azure QnA with data source as secure API

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

My legacy system is CRM, it has lots of knowledge base articles and users keeps on adding data on it so it’s dynamic.

Now I want to take knowledge base data to my QnA service and take advantage of LUIS with QnA to develop chatbot which will be installed in my companies website.

## microsoftluis

## qnamaker

Comment: So you are looking for how you could implement or code example for  `QnA maker`  knowledge base on your application?

Comment: No, I want to know if we can give any external secured link to QnA.     Share point API we can give but is it possible to give CRM api and QnA will extract data from that API

Comment: What did you mean by external secure link? I am bit confused! But back to your question, Yes you can use your knowledge base any where you want through a simple API call which is secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/knowledge-base#data-source-locations):

> Content is brought into a knowledge base from a data source. Data source locations are **public URLs** or files, **which do not require authentication**.

I have bolded the important parts. So, if the URL is publicly accessible from the internet (not only from an internal network), AND does not require authentication, then QnA Maker will be able to import it.

Support for secured SharePoint files has recently been added, you can read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/add-sharepoint-datasources).

In your case you might have to do one of the following to get the data out:

- Write a piece of software to crawl through and scrape the contents from the CRM system
- Write a piece of software that accesses the data store/API behind the CRM system

Then use the [QnA Maker REST APIs](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/5ac266295b4ccd1554da75ff) to update your knowledge base.

There may be other options that are a better approach in your case, but due to my limited knowledge of your internal systems I cannot make any more specific recommendations.